# Xcode Unknown class l in Interface Builder file Glitch

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

I keep encountering what I believe to be a bug in Xcode version Version 9.4.1. My code will run fine, then after making no adjustments to the storyboard/interface that would necessarily affect the ID or any of my outlets, I will get the error `Unknown class l in Interface Builder file.`

I have tried investigating, but no luck. I can't find any objects in my storyboard with the class `l`. Last time, I was able to fix the error by hitting undo a few times. However, hitting undo is not fixing the problem this time. Cleaning the project via `SHIFT+CMD+K` and restarting Xcode also have no affect.

Anyone else run into this error or have any idea how I could fix it?

Comment: Opengin your storyboard as source code (it's XML in fact, by doing right click on it, open as), and looking for `"l"` (with the double quotes), you couldn't find it?

Comment: Nope, but thank you for the suggestion! The program ended up sorting itself out "magically" after opening and closing Xcode a few more times... Strange.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

After opening and closing Xcode a few more times, the problem seems to have "magically" sorted itself out. Odd, right? While I shouldn't look a gift horse in the mouth, I can't help but remain curious about what could've possibly caused this bug in the first place.